# Issue with Kafka consumer exceptions

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

When consuming messages using Kafka, I often encounter the following exception after consuming for a period of time.

```
error:
[10:59:59:248] [ERROR] .kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.error():149 - Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'java.lang.IllegalStateException's; no record information is available
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:204) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1901) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1350) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected error code 5 while fetching at offset 50813686 from topic-partition 1256017579-da8621a5-7a33-43e1-bd67-1afc7eb1cc45-0
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.initializeCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:1392) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:660) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1304) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1614) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1589) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1390) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1304) ~[spring-kafka-2.9.10.jar!/:2.9.10]
    ... 3 more
```

Configuration：

```
autoOffsetReset: earliest
enableAutoCommit: true
autoCommitInterval: 1000
maxPollRecords: 50
maxPollIntervalMs: 300000
sessionTimeoutMs: 30000
heartbeatIntervalMs: 10000
keyDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
valueDeserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

What could be the cause of this issue and how can it be resolved?